# When is a curve in $\mathbb P^n$ a canonical curve?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Consider over $\mathbb C$. Let $C\subseteq\mathbb P^n$ be a smooth curve. Let $g$ be the genus of $C$. Let $H$ denote the hyperplane divisor on $\mathbb P^n$. When $C$ is a canonical curve, then $K_C=H|_C$ and $n=g-1$. I wonder whether the following inverse is true.

> Let $C\subseteq\mathbb P^n$ be a smooth curve. If $H|_C=K_C$, then $n=g-1$ and $C$ is a canonical curve.

In *Principles of Algebraic Geometry* by Griffths and Harris, bottom of p.258, it seems the above statement is used. If the above statement is wrong, can you explain why Griffths and Harris claim that $C$ is a canonical curve of genus 4?
[image]

---

2023-02-08

As the comment by Sasha shows, the statement is false in general. Then my question reduces to why Griffths and Harris make the claim.

Comment: No, $C$ could be a projection of the canonical curve onto a smaller space, or its embedding into a larger space, or a combination of these two.

Comment: They are not making that claim: they are also assuming that $n = g-1$.